# Is to possible to write and load your own version of core Java classes?

Tags: java, class, classloader

I was asked this question during an interview -"Is to possible to write and load your own version of core Java classes (Like String,Object etc)". I said no but the interviewer wanted to know what checks does Java have to prevent this. To understand this I wrote the below piece of code in eclipse

```
package java.lang;
public final class String {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String();
    }

}
```

I was expecting the compilation to fail because Java already has a String class in java.lang package. But the compilation went through and I got the below error when I ran the program --

```
Error: Main method not found in class java.lang.String, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Why was the compilation successful considering String is already present in java.lang and how does Java block loading core classes by developers?

Comment: *Can you write your own version of core java classes?* Generally yes, as long as you aren't extending final classes or doing other things that are a compiler no-no. *Can you include those classes in the core java runtime environment?* Not that I know of, no. Also, compilation fails for me when I specify `java.lang` as a package in a file not in the core JRE, are you sure your Eclipse is correctly configured?

Answer (score 3):

`javac` has to compile the core classes.

There are checks done at runtime to prevent you loading duplicate classes.

- You can't load any classes starting with `java.`. I believe, this was done to stop Microsoft doing naughty incompatible things.
- You can't load two classes with the same name with the same class loader instance.
- By default the class loader will check the parent loader before loading a class. This one is overridable (with the relevant security permissions).

You can start a JVM with different core classes, though this wll be implementation specific. Up to JDK 8 you could use `-Xbootclass/p:` selective replace classes.

Comment: Even if you use two classloaders to load two classes with the same name, the runtime won't confuse them. See "loading constraints" in the JLS.